# ">" is encoded to "&gt;"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor, character-encoding

Probably, someone will be able to explain me, why ">" sign is encoded to `"&gt;"`.
I am using mvc razor and some my cshtml view uses script that you can find below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var thumbnails = $("img.thumbnail");
        thumbnails.each(function () {
            $(this).load(function () {
                if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
                    $(this).css("height", "100%");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css("width", "100%");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Chrome browser throws exception:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   ;

in next line:

```
if ($(this).height() &gt; $(this).width()) {
```

What reason(s) can be to do this encoding/transform (except for curves of hands :D)?

Or some way to solve it.

Comment: This is expected behaviour inside the document, but not inside the `script` tag. Strange.

Comment: is cshtml XML? If so, then you'll need to wrap all of your JS in CDATA comments.

Comment: The reason to do it is that your template engine thinks the output is supposed to be readable in the browser, so it's changing the `<`, `>`, and `&` characters to their HTML-entity equivalents. How to fix it depends on what exactly you're doing to send that stuff to the user.

Comment: Is it possible that whatever tool you are using to upload the JavaScript is encoding the internals? It looks like the JavaScript is encoded to avoid XSS (Cross Site Scripting), and then added into the `javascript` tag? Just a guess, because as Pekka mentioned it is weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var thumbnails = $("img.thumbnail");
            thumbnails.each(function () {
                $(this).load(function () {
                    if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
                        $(this).css("height", "100%");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).css("width", "100%");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    ]]>
</script>
```

Or else put your javascript in an external javascript file.

(I post this answer having read your question comments)

Comment: Thank you! There is nice article that describes how to solve this problem: http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm - anyways, I need  understand reason of this behavior. Thank you all again!